# I keep getting the "OAuth consumer key/secret combination not supplied" error message

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, web-crawler

for my school project I got to collect data from twitter. Now I have found the following code, but I keep getting the OAuth consumer key/secret combination not supplied error, and I have no clue how to fix it. Any solutions?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import twitter4j.IDs;
import twitter4j.Paging;
import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
// TODO: preserve network distribution: normalize number of nodes
// TODO: discard re-tweet option
// TODO: multifocal approach

public class TwitterCrawler {
    public static final String FOCAL_NODE = "euromast";
    public static final int NUMBER_LINKS = 5;
public static final int NUMBER_NODES = 40;
public static final int NUMBER_STATUSES = 20;
public String networkOutputFile = "Users/Chris/Desktop/data/twitter.csv";
public String contentOutputFile = "/Users/Chris/Desktop/data/twitter2.txt";
private static Twitter twitter;

public TwitterCrawler() {
    try {
        twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        AccessToken token = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
        System.out.println("Access Token " + token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public HashSet<User> getFriends(User u, int max) throws Exception {
    HashSet<User> ret = new HashSet<User>();
    long cursor = -1;
    IDs ids;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        ids = twitter.getFriendsIDs(u.getScreenName(), cursor);
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.getIDs().length && i < max; i++) {
            long id = ids.getIDs()[i];
            ret.add(twitter.showUser(id));
        }
        count++;
    } while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0 && count < max);
    return ret;
}

public void crawl() throws TwitterException, IOException {
    ArrayList<User> ret = new ArrayList<User>();
    HashMap<User, HashSet<Link>> links = new HashMap<User, HashSet<Link>>();
    HashMap<User, ResponseList<Status>> statuses = new HashMap<User, ResponseList<Status>>();
    String[] startnodes = { FOCAL_NODE };
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(startnodes);
    // ret.addAll(users);
    for (int i = 0; i < users.size() && ret.size() < NUMBER_NODES; i++) {
        User user = (User) users.get(i);// it.next();
        try {
            // save links
            Iterator it2 = this.getFriends(user, NUMBER_LINKS).iterator(); // this
                                                                            // might
                                                                            // throw
                                                                            // an
                                                                            // "unauthorized"
                                                                            // exception
                                                                            // that's
                                                                            // why
                                                                            // it
                                                                            // should
                                                                            // come
                                                                            // first
            links.put(user, new HashSet<Link>());
            int countFriends = 0;
            while (it2.hasNext() && countFriends < NUMBER_LINKS) {
                User friend = (User) it2.next();
                Link l = new Link(user, friend);
                links.get(user).add(l);
                users.add(friend);
                countFriends++;
            }
            // successfully fetched user info, save user
            ret.add(user);
            // save statuses
            Paging paging = new Paging(1, NUMBER_STATUSES);
            ResponseList<Status> userStatuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(
                    user.getId(), paging);
            statuses.put(user, userStatuses);
            System.out.println("Done with: @" + user.getScreenName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error - not authorized for: "
                    + user.getScreenName() + " - skipping...");
            // remove links to people that had "unauthorized access"
            // exception
            for (HashSet<Link> linksPerUser : links.values()) {
                ArrayList<Link> markedForRemoval = new ArrayList<Link>();
                for (Link curLink : linksPerUser) {
                    if (curLink.from.getId() == user.getId()
                            || curLink.to.getId() == user.getId()) {
                        markedForRemoval.add(curLink);
                    }
                }
                for (Link toRemoveLink : markedForRemoval) {
                    linksPerUser.remove(toRemoveLink);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    saveToCSVFile(ret, links);
    saveContentToFile(statuses);
}

/*
 * Saves the network in NET format (Pajek)
 * http://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/pajek-net-format/
 */
public void saveToNetFile(ArrayList<User> users,
        HashMap<User, HashSet<Link>> links,
        HashMap<User, ResponseList<Status>> statuses) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
            new File(networkOutputFile));
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fout);
    String linksString = "*Edges\n";
    ps.println("*Vertices " + users.size());
    for (User user : users) {
        ps.println(user.getId() + " \"" + user.getScreenName() + "\"");
        if (links.containsKey(user)) {
            for (Link link : links.get(user)) {
                linksString += link.toString() + "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    ps.println(linksString);
    ps.close();
    fout.close();
}

public void saveToCSVFile(ArrayList<User> users,
        HashMap<User, HashSet<Link>> links) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
            new File(networkOutputFile));
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fout);
    for (HashSet<Link> linksPerUser : links.values()) {
        if (linksPerUser.size() > 0) {
            ps.print(linksPerUser.iterator().next().from.getScreenName()
                    + ";");
            for (Link curLink : linksPerUser) {
                ps.print(curLink.to.getScreenName() + ";");
            }
            ps.print("\n");
        }
    }
    ps.close();
    fout.close();
}

public void saveContentToFile(HashMap<User, ResponseList<Status>> statuses)
        throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(
            new File(contentOutputFile));
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fout);
    for (ResponseList<Status> statusesPerUser : statuses.values()) {
        if (statusesPerUser.size() > 0) {
            ps.println(statusesPerUser.iterator().next().getUser()
                    .getScreenName()
                    + " " + statusesPerUser.size());
            for (Status curStatus : statusesPerUser) {
                ps.println(curStatus.getText().replace("\n", "") + ""); // very
                                                                        // important:
                                                                        // replace
                                                                        // line
                                                                        // breaks
            }
        }
    }
    ps.close();
    fout.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TwitterCrawler cn = new TwitterCrawler();
        cn.crawl();
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to lookup users: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class Link {
    public User from;
    public User to;

    public Link(User f, User t) {
        from = f;
        to = t;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || !(this.getClass() != obj.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        Link other = (Link) obj;
        return this.from.getId() == other.from.getId()
                && this.to.getId() == other.to.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return String.valueOf(this.from.getId()).hashCode()
                + String.valueOf(this.to.getId()).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.from.getId()) + " "
                + String.valueOf(this.to.getId());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In which line do you get this error? Is it `twitter.getOAuthAccessToken()`?

Comment: Yes, I keep getting the error in that line.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit it's been two years since I last created a twitter application. But I remember that the authentication process is complex and rather tedious. I can' find any authentication steps in your code so I guess that your problem stems from that fact. You have a lot of choices how you want to authenticate your crawler. But as far as I can see you only want access friendlists of users.

For this use case you only need a **single user authentication**. 
In order to obtain one follow the steps on [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only).

Please note that there will be a restraint in the number of requests you can make.